# WordPress WPML - Language code exists

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

i have a wordpress site with WPML. In my site I have English and Russian setup, And now i want to add Spanish. I try to add the Spanish language like this:

[image]

But i got the error: Language code exists.
How can I install a language that "already exists"?

Thanks :)

Comment: Check link for help:- https://wpml.org/forums/topic/language-code-exists-hebrew/

Comment: The solution there is really intense & extreme. And at the end it was not clear whether the solution worked or not. There is no simpler solution?

Comment: I don't know. At least try that one may it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Spanish language is natively supported by WPML so you don't have to add it manually like you are doing now. Under "WPML" -> "Languages" you can click on a button "Add languages" and just check the checkbox voor Spanish.

Comment: I dont have checkbox there